# Java casting from float to int

Tags: java, casting

I have this algorithm set (In my mind) which requires me to cast float to int many times in a loop(about 300 times for each 16 milli seconds) . My question is this:

**How costly is process of casting from float to int in java/android and will it cause the game to slow down ?**

Is it cheap enough to be implemented by my game? if not, what are the other options to convert decimal to integer?

Edit: **Question solved!**

Comment: I'd say that you are safe with casting it to an int 300 times in 16 milliseconds. The question about how costly the process is is interesting, but I think you have better things to worry about.

Comment: 300 times / 16 milli-seconds isn't a lot.

Comment: Have you done any performance profiling?

Comment: it isn't a lot on its own but I have some other algorithms to be implemented in the 16 milli seconds including the time taken by android system to draw the frame...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg "I'd say that youre safe"? maybe you should cite your sources? :)

Comment: Why not cast outside the loop if you're casting that many times inside and maybe add one after the loop ends?

Comment: @RubberMallet I knew that would bite me back ;)

Comment: @Tejaswi Rana No.. I should cast it 300-400 times each frame.. It is some trick i figured out in my mind to avoid 300-400 multiplication

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most FP chipsets have float -> int and int -> float in hardware.

Comment: @HotLicks for android processors as well?

Comment: Fine... So the casting process is just cheap as that of integer addition... Mark this question as solved...

Comment: The only question is how much of the ARM floating point instruction set is actually implemented, vs simulated.  It's my impression that on phones it's mostly implemented, since the arithmetic is needed both for graphics and for signal processing.  On ARM processors used in other environments this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cast from float to int doesn't cost any more than any other assignment statement. It is handled by the hardware. An assignment (depending on the architecture) typically costs a single cycle or one trip through the pipeline (very, very fast). I wouldn't worry about the impact of this conversion on your performance.